# German equivalent of “Mutual weirdness forever”

Tags: english-to-german, phrase-request

> mutual weirdness forever

is a common form of congratulation for weddings, and gift cards with this wording can be found in endless numbers.

[image]

How would you say this in German? I need this for a gift for a couple who describes their relationship this way.

As a literal translation (“gegenseitige Seltsamkeit für immer”) obviously would not work – is there an established cultural equivalent in German?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann tempted to do it myself. But I’m afraid that translating what is based on a Dr. Seuss (or not) quote is nearly impossible - because the average German won’t know and hence not recognize the source and the implied meaning.

Comment: @Stephie  Any idea which of Theodor Geisel's books (or whatever) could be the origin of that phrase?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann [probably none](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2014/02/14/love-weird/amp/)... having been quoted, re-quoted and cross-posted on social media until it got a cutesy way of saying “love”.

Comment: @Stephie  - Good source, though, for de-atttribution of this phrase to (respectively from) Ted Geisel.

Comment: If they are English speaking I'd go with the English saying. Although not used in German, it's still a nice saying and if they can understand it it surely brings the intention across. Also it seems more personal, as it's coming from you (and your culture).

Comment: @amikayave: please add your/the english understanding of "mutual weirdness forever".

Comment: I deleted most of the comments since I consider them to be addressed now. If you still think that something needs addressing, please post a new comment. Please do not post answers in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

As the meaning - or rather the pragmatics - of *Mutual weirdness forever* seems to be: being used as a jokular form of congratulation for weddings (or other love-related occasions), but a litteral translation to German is not possible with usable results, one could try to search for expressions in German that would transport the idea of good wishes for the longevity of the relationship in an ironic way, in completely different words.

Here some suggestions:

> Jeder Topf findet seinen Deckel

This is a proverb, usually used to express the opinion that at some time in life two persons will find their significant other. Used for a wedding, it sounds a bit tongue-in-cheek, as obviously the couple is being compared to kitchen equipment and thus not taken very seriously.

> Jedem Tierchen sein Pläsierchen

This proverb is usually used to express the idea that different people do have different tastes and preferences. Applied on a wedding situation, it would be a friendlyly disrespectful way of acknowledging the relationship. (When hearing *Tierchen* I am thinking of a small mammal, for example a squirrel, so I imagine a couple of squirrels in love.)

I must emphasize however that the ironical use of these two proverbs at weddings is not at all established or common in the German speaking part of the world. I have never seen anybody use them on a wedding gift card or whatever. I just searched for possible ways to create something more or less equivalent to "Mutual weirdness forever".

**Solution for real life:**

Why not taking the English original? People in Germany are pretty much used to English catch phrases, your friends definitely understand English, and the card is a gift from you personally, so it is a genuine reference. - Unless you want to be extra-funny (or weird) and provide a German equivalent that everbody makes either frown or start because it is so unusual. In this case, of course, you may resort to the literal translation SwissCodeMen provided in his first comment:

> Gegenseitige Verwirrung für immer!

(which may be funny for people who know the English original and make the connection)

---

Footnote:

I also considered

> Bis dass der Tod euch scheidet

as this is a formula that is actually used in wedding ceremonies of the Christian denominations, but using this on a gift card or so would rather sound like a dark, even malevolent way of thinking and can definitely not be recommended. It is bitter irony, but you were looking for joyful irony.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion.  I'm going to hold off on using "to death do us part" for obvious reasons.

Comment: you have been more than helpful with providing alternatives and explanations. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @amikayave - My pleasure. - As for your eventual decision: Why not taking the English original. Your friends obviously understand English, and it is a gift from you, so it is a nice reference to your culture. - Unless you want to be extra-funny (or weird) and provide a German equivalent - which, as we saw, is however not that easy...

Comment: In this context I would not translate "weirdness" with "Verwirrung". I think "weirdness" is used as in "you're kind of weird and I don't get you" so "Gegenseitiges Befremden" seems better IMHO. But I concur regarding using the original English phrase unless the intended audience might not understand it.

Answer (score -1):

Without any intended meaning in English supplied (I also note, that none of your cards tries to depict something exceeding the phrase; so as assumed in some comments it might be a meme without much substance) a German translation seems to be

> Bleibt verrückt auf einander (/ verliebt in einander)!

but this is so far from established, that I don't rember to have read it even once.

The established standard phrases sound comparatively boring (e.g. *Herzlichen Glückwunsch zur Hochzeit*).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion..I like the "stay crazy about each other".  Although it's not direct, it has a similar meaning to the original requested phrase.